# What does this "that" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, that

What does this "that" mean?
I don't think this "that" is both a relative pronoun and a noun clause.

> "Exactly how do I care about her, **that** I'm letting this weigh me down so much?"

Thank you.

Comment: That’s a clumsy sentence to begin with. _How_ does not pair well with _that_ in the relative clause. “Why do I care so much about her that I’m letting this weigh me down?” would be a normal use, with _so much… that_; but “How do I care about her that I’m letting this weigh me down” is unusual.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I couldn't understand the original sentence because "how" is used for "why" and "so much" is put at the end of the sentence. Now I've understood. Thank you!

Comment: There's no relative clause. This is not relative "that", but a subordinator introducing a declarative content clause in adjunct function. Semantically the adjunct can be regarded as resultative: the presupposition of the question can be roughly glossed as "I care about her to x extent with the result that I'm letting it weigh me down".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you! I didn't know the adjunct and it's used as resultative. My question's just been clear thanks to you.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, you’re right—I meant to say ‘subordinate clause’, not ‘relative clause’.